# nslookup for SRV records (or any non-A records) in non-interactive mode

Tags: domain-name-system, command-line-interface, nslookup

Is the anyway to run nslookup (Centos 5 or Windows) such that it will look up record types other than A, without having to go to interactive mode and using `set type=`?  For example, I'd like a command like the following:

```
nslookup --type=SRV _ldap._tcp.mydomain.com
```

Answer (score 34):

You actually almost had it. On both window (at least my Win7 box I have here) and Ubuntu you would do `nslookup -type=SRV _ldap._tcp.mydomain.com` (notice the single dash)

Comment: `nslookup -q=MX serverfault.com` also works (except, replace MX with SRV and whatnot)

Answer (score 9):

This work for me

```
nslookup -q=SRV _ldap._tcp.mydomain.com
```

So
    nslookup -q=SRV _sip._tls.tan-ha.com

```
Server:  myhost.local  
Address:  1.2.3.4 (my ip)

Non-authoritative answer:  
_sip._tls.tan-ha.com    SRV service location:  
          priority       = 100  
          weight         = 1  
          port           = 443  
          svr hostname   = sipdir.myotherdomainorso.com  

sipdir.myotherdomainorso.com  internet address = 110.12.23.34  
sipdir.myotherdomainorso.com  AAAA IPv6 address = 1111:111:ffff:3004::35
```

Answer (score 4):

It appears the nslookup man page isn't correct anymore.

<strike>nslookup doesn't have a powerful non-interactive mode:</strike>

```
      "Non-interactive mode is used to print just the name and
       requested information for a host or domain"
```

Instead, use host(1):

```
host -t SRV example.com
```